# PHP Logic - How to handle score ties?

Tags: php, logic

I'm trying to distribute prizes based on scores. I'm having trouble with my logic when it comes to **TIE's**. Can anyone give me **logic pointers** on handling a tie between 3 or more people?

**UPDATE:**
The Goal is this --

1. Make an ARRAY of the people who have tied (Only them)
2. Know what POSITION those people are in.

I have a few sample phases you can skim through:

**Example 1** - Works with 0 Ties

```
<?php
function give_prize($a, $b) {return;}

$prize = array(500, 250, 75);

$user = array(
    'user1' => 650,
    'user2' => 500,
    'user3' => 200,
    'user4' => 100,
);

$prize_count = count($prize);

for ($i = 0; $i < $prize_count; $i++) {
    give_prize($user[$i], $prize[$i]);
}
```

**Example 2** - Works with 1 Tie (Is it a good way?)

```
<?php   
for ($i = 0; $i < $prize_count; $i++) {

    if (isset($user[$i+1])) {
        if ($user[$i] == $user[$i++]) {
            // My Tie breaker code
        }
    }
}
```

**But what would I do in a tie of 3 or 4 people? Should I follow the above and do more if checks?**

Comment: It depends on the rules for a tie. If two people tie for first place, do they both receive the first prize? In other words, do you give out four prizes instead of three? If not, do you split the prizes among the users who tie at each level?

Comment: I'm not sure what your tie breaker code is trying to do... how does it break the tie?

Comment: Hey guys, Im not looking for tie breaker code. Im only trying to figure out a good way to match all the people who have tied. :)

Comment: `if ($user[$i] == $user[$i++])` this always is a true, because you used postincrementation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start by grouping users by score and then sorting those groups in descending order. Once that is complete it will be easier to assign prizes no matter what rules you have.

```
$usersByScore = array();
foreach ($user as $name => $score) {
    $usersByScore[$score][] = $name;
}
krsort($usersByScore);
```

For example, this turns the input `$user`

```
$user = array(
    'user1' => 500,
    'user2' => 400,
    'user3' => 750,
    'user4' => 500,
);
```

into `$usersByScore`:

```
$usersByScore = array(
    750 => array('user3'),
    500 => array('user1', 'user4'),
    400 => array('user2'),
);
```

Now you can issue prizes however you like.

Comment: Wow, that actually might be exactly what I was trying to get to!